# ASP.NET Page already visited ever before?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

Is there a mechanism in ASP.NET to detect whether page was ever visited before?
(Without storing to database or Application object)
I'm running the site on IIS.

```
localhost/page?a=1&b=2 - not visited
localhost/page?a=1&b=3 - not visited
localhost/page?a=1&b=2 - already visited!
```

P.S. the detection should be if it was ever visited by anyone. Let's say some hash is generated in querystring:

```
localhost/page?a=83abd83de6514ba0a0e5ce620eb1d43e
```

I need to check if that hash has already been "used".

How? To me, simplest way (without storing into db) is to find out if the page with this querystring was ever opened.

Comment: Visited by whom? Anyone? Same user twice?

Comment: Anyone. If the page was ever "opened", if the querystring has been "used"

Comment: Doesn't seem possible without a persistent storage.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Is there some component that would allow me to access IIS logs and read from there possible URLs?

Comment: @Dalibor If you would like to access IIS logs, maybe you could consider writing the querystring into a static file instead. Because for me, both are doing the same thing. Furthermore, logs may include noises that you don't want to read.

Comment: Couldn't you just use a cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create files in "~/App_Data/" then check if file exists.

Your code will like bellow:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var message = "not visited";

    var chk = Guid.TryParse(Page.Request.QueryString["a"], out var guid);

    var hash = chk ? guid.ToString("N").ToUpper() :
        BitConverter.ToString(MD5.Create()
            .ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Request.RawUrl)))
            .Replace("-", string.Empty);

    var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + hash);

    if (File.Exists(path))
        message = "already visited!";
    else if (!chk)
        File.WriteAllText(path, string.Empty);

    Label1.Text = message;
}
```

PS For any page in website, put like code in Application_BeginRequest event in Global.asax

Comment: I like it. I award bounty to you.

Answer (score 1):

Several ways to do that:

1. if your IIS enabled the access log, you can analysis it's access log
2. if you have an service gateway before IIS, you can analysis it's access log
3. if you have an nginx before IIS, you can analysis it's access log
4. if you have an F5 before IIS, you can analysis it's access log
5. if your app is on the cloud, you can analysis it's access log
6. if these logs do not have enough info, you'd better implement your own log class
7. you can also try to log these urls in redis(K-V, or hyper-log-log, or bloom-filter, depends on what you want to do)

Comment: Very good, but I was asking for coding solution, and I don't have access to the server nor IIS. Thank you anyway.